# Pathogen won't load nerdtree or other bundles

Tags: plugin-managers

**How to troubleshoot pathogen?**

Using Mac OSX El Capitan. Vim 7.4 MacOS X version, not MacVim. Running from terminal.

I can run nerdtree as a plugin, but won't work with pathogen. Same case with other plugins.

I have followed the install directions closely at https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree

**From the `~/.vimrc`:**

```
set nocompatible
filetype off " Pathogen needs to run before plugin indent on
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
colorscheme murphy
inoremap ii <Esc>`^
```

**From `:scriptnames`**

```
 1: ~/.vimrc
 2: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
 3: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
 4: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
 5: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
 6: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
 7: ~/.vim/bundle/todo.txt-vim/ftdetect/todo.vim
 8: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
 9: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
10: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/colors/murphy.vim
11: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
12: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
13: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
14: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
15: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
16: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
17: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
18: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
19: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
20: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
21: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
22: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
23: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
24: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
25: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/event.vim
26: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/notifier.vim
27: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
28: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
29: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
30: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-easymotion/plugin/EasyMotion.vim
31: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown-preview/plugin/vim-markdown-preview.vim
32: /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/modula2.vim`
```

**Directory structure is**

```
~/.vim
~/.vim/autoload
~/.vim/bundle
~/.vim/plugin
~/.vim/lib
etc, etc
```

`~/.vim/bundle` has `/nerdtree` from cloned from github.

File loads in Vim but no nerdtree or other plugins are active.

Comment: please clarify what exactly does not work. As you can see from the :scriptnames output, nerdtree plugin is loaded. Perhaps you should ask at the plugin's issue tracker

Comment: Define "won't work".

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, I was calling `:NERD_Tree`, not `:NERDTree`

Also added to my .vimrc:

`autocmd vimenter * NERDTree`

"Problem" solved.